# Control over the audience targeting dialog

Tags: 2010, audience-targeting

I have a customer which find it non-userfriendly to have the option to choose between "Global Audience", "Distribution/Security Groups" and "SharePoint Groups". Instead they want to have a dropdown with, e.g. "Location", "Country" and then see the various groups beneath them. Is it possible to change these OOTB search scopes for audience targeting? Because now you have to know what group to search for, instead of seeing which groups are available.